# Writing SQL to use the 'Value' of a 'Project Type' column as a 'Parameter' to pass to PowerBi

Tags: sql, powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tableau-desktop

Our Company is currently building visuals with Tableau, and we are now re-building our 'Views' to make them perform better as were transitioning anyway,  What I am trying to achieve is this:  Tableau allows you to create a 'Parameter' based off a Value to allow me to allocate sales to different groups so that they can be changed/selected by the user with the parameter filter and not have to manually filter out other departments and sales types.  I am hoping to write a "parameter" in Snowflake so that I can pre-write the calculations rather than adding additional calculations in PowerBi later.

### The current parameter is set like this which I have tried a number of ways to re-create in SQL (without using a stored procedure)

```
`IF [Parameters].[Project Type] = 'Client Non-Bill'
THEN(IF [Project Type] = 'Client Nonbill'
THEN [Profit YTD]
ELSE 0
END)
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Project Type] = 'Lost'
THEN(IF [Project Type] = 'Lost'
THEN [Profit YTD]
ELSE 0
END)
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Project Type] = 'Sales'
THEN(IF [Project Type] = 'Sales'
THEN [Profit YTD]
ELSE 0
END)
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Project Type] = 'All'
THEN [Profit YTD]
END
`
```

---

### When I write a parameter to allocate the different values:

```
`case [Project Type] <> 0
then if [Project Type] = 'Client-Nonbill'
then [Profit YTD]
else 0

elseif [Project Type] = 'Lost'
THEN [Profit YTD]
else 0

elseif [Project Type] = 'Sales'
then [Profit YTD]
else 0 end as [ProjectParameter]`
```

### using this I am hoping to be able to write a statement like the below example to match on the parameter so that it will pull based on the different project types rather than creating a TON of separate calculations:   However is simply will not work right now and am just hoping for any guidance!

### ****Please keep in mind this transition is very new, and I have not worked with PowerBi in the past****

```
`
IF [Parameters].[Project Type] = 'Client Non-Bill'
THEN(IF [Project Type] = 'Client Nonbill'
THEN [Direct Non Billable Expenses LTD]
ELSE 0
END)
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Project Type] = 'Lost'
THEN(IF [Project Type] = 'Lost'
THEN [Direct Non Billable Expenses LTD]
ELSE 0
END)
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Project Type] = 'Sales'
THEN(IF [Project Type] = 'Sales'
THEN [Direct Non Billable Expenses LTD]
ELSE 0
END)
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Project Type] = 'All'
THEN [Direct Non Billable Expenses LTD]
END`
```

Comment: It may be worth looking into how tableau generated the SQL for those parameters. 
check out this [article on finding custom SQL](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000FYbazSAD/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-custom-sql-code-embedded-in-a-workbook-when-you-no-longer-have-access-to-the-server) and the [Tableau Document API](https://tableau.github.io/document-api-python/) for pulling parameters out of Tableau XML files.

Comment: Hey @Anomaly, I just found [this tableau functionality](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/perf_record_interpret_server.htm) that shows the generated queries Tableau makes for performance measuring. Scroll down to the "Query" section of that link and I think it may be what you are looking for.